# Get all visible elements on web page

Tags: xpath, selenium, firebug, css-selectors

I need to get all visible elements on web page to click on them, but it's too long to check each element with .displayed? Selenium method. Is there another way to create array with only visible elements to avoid checking.

Seems I need only non-grey elements from firebug.

```
//*[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]
```

request doesn't solve my problem, because not all of invisible elements has such attribute.

Comment: are these input, anchor tags, or just any random element or some combination?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C#.NET  you can use a lambda expression to remove any elements that are not displayed. If not then this wouldn't work. This will get you every single anchor element, input element, and select element.  Then it would remove any that were not displayed.

```cs
browserDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");
List<IWebElement> theseElements = browserDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).ToList();
theseElements.AddRange(browserDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("input")).ToList());
theseElements.AddRange(browserDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("select")).ToList());
theseElements.RemoveAll(i => !i.Displayed); //LAMBDA EXPRESSION
foreach (IWebElement element in theseElements)
{
    element.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't tagged but using the [jQuery visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), it's as easy as `:visible`.

Comment: this doesn't play well with selenium

Comment: @CBRRacer: According to some casual Google searches, one *can* hook jQuery to Selenium, but not having used Selenium myself I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: jQuery selectors are not natively supported by Selenium, though. This by itself isn't a good answer.

Comment: @BoltClock while you can hook them in depending on the framework you are running (RoR, Python, Java, .NET) it will make a big difference as far as the amount of support that those plugins provide and how effective they work.  typically running jQuery in selenium is more of a hack than an answer and in many cases there are better answers.